# postgres схема и данные

Tags: sql, резервное-копирование, psql

Есть база данных, у нее в таблицах в некоторых нет primary key и появились копии записей.
Есть бекап этой базы с ключами.

Нужно базу без ключей починить. Руками тупо и долго.

Придумал как:
Сливаю со старой базы схему

```
pg_dump --schema database > database_sheme.sql
```

Сливаю с новой базы данные

```
pg_dump --data-only database > database_data.sql
```

Создаю новую базу

```
creatdb database_new
```

Заливаю схему - все гуд

```
psql database_new < database_sheme.sql
```

Заливаю данные

```
psql database_new < database_data.sql
```

Пишет что нарушают условие уникальности - ну и отлично.
В итоге после того как зальются данные - ничего в таблицах нет!!!
При чем место постгрес занимает больше...
В чем проблема?? Даже в интернете ничего подобного кроме одной статьи не нашел.
[Статья](http://www.sinyawskiy.ru/relation_not_exist.html)

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql полноценная транзакционная СУБД. Ошибка запроса откатывает все изменения, выполненные в этой транзакции, а поскольку вы импортируете данные не одной транзакцией - то каждый `copy` рассматривается как отдельная транзакция.

Дисковое место было занято записью строк до обнаружения ошибки и будет отмечено свободным в ходе работы процесса `autovacuum` (либо ручным `vacuum`). Будет ли место автоматически возвращено файловой системе или останется зарезервированным под таблицу - есть варианты. Таблицы в вашем случае должны будут сжаться обратно до 8кб, индексы уменьшаться автоматически не будут.

Вам необходимо написать запросы по удалению дублирующихся данных. Или написать запрос который сгенерирует запросы для удаления. Задача "удали какие-нибудь любые мешающие новому constraint данные" звучит слишком странно и postgresql не предлагает средств по её выполнению.

Впрочем, если данные в базе вам действительно настолько не нужны, а версия базы 9.5 или старше - то можете сделать `pg_dump --data-only --inserts`, затем в полученные `insert`-запросы дописать `on conflict do nothing`.

Comment: То-есть по моей схеме - не получиться сделать? Если к copy будут ошибки то данные не будут импортированы?

Comment: Именно так. copy в том числе или добавляет все данные или не добавляет ничего